# Declare variable with a dot at the begining in R

Tags: r

The crux of the question is the same as the Title,

Somebody knows or could provide infromation about ".variables" in R?

```
.variable<-1
class(.variable) 
[1] 1
[1] "numeric"
```

As far as I know is like a hidden variable because it isnt appearing on the global environment of R studio.

So, the point would be to define:

- What it is?
- what is used for?
- some examples

Comment: You can use `ls(all.names = TRUE)` to get all the object names

Comment: thx akrun but, the main target would be also to define it as a concept, they are hidden variables? which uses they have? some information to see their uses.. thx a lot

Comment: You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526467/what-does-the-dot-mean-in-r-personal-preference-naming-convention-or-more)

Comment: thx it was useful

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The prefix dot notation in `R` specifies a hidden object that cannot be accessed directly through `ls` unless you use `ls(all.names = TRUE)`. The purpose of this is for developers of `R` packages to have some way to hide the implementation details of their functions from users, making their package more user-friendly, as described more fully on [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/use-hidden-advanced-arguments-for-user-friendly-functions/) (and quoted briefly here in case of link rot):

> Lets say that you are developing the function use_me(). If the details you want the users to control are actually arguments of other functions used inside use_me(), then you can simplify your function by using the ... argument. This argument is very well explained at The three-dots construct in R (Burns, 2013). It is very useful and can greatly simplify your life as a developer. Plus, it reduces the length of your help pages, thus making your package more user friendly.
>
> However, if some of the details in use_me() are not arguments to other functions, then the common strategy is to write two functions. One is a low level function with arguments for all the details which might or might not export. Then, you write a second function that is a wrapper for the low level function and pre-specifies values for all the details. See the next minimal example:

```
# Don't export this function
.use_me <- function(arg1, arg2, verbose = TRUE) {
    if(verbose) message(paste(Sys.time(), 'working'))
    pmax(arg1, arg2)
}

#' @export
use_me <- function(arg1, ...) {
    .use_me(arg1, 0, ...)
}
```

This is very similar to Python's use of the single underscore to prevent automatically loading objects from packages. In both cases the practice appears to be a naming convention - outside of their specified uses (in `R`'s case, hiding the object in the environment) there isn't really any other outcome of using the notation (according to the comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753887/how-do-hidden-variables-behave-in-r) at least, and after scanning the documentation myself).

For examples of this in actual use, see the help for `colSums` or `trace`.