# variable name starting with ". "

Tags: r, variables, environment-variables, global-variables

I can see that variable names in R can also be named by starting with **"."**.

For example, ***.data, .height***, etc.,

But these variables are not getting listed in **global variables**, and also it is not possible to delete the variable by ***rm()***.

For example, ***rm(.data), rm(.height)***, etc.,

Where such variables are getting stored exactly? What is the lifecycle of those variables? Is there any use-case?

Comment: You **can** delete them using `rm()`. I don't know where you heard that you cannot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553480/declare-variable-with-a-dot-at-the-begining-in-r

Comment: They can be stored wherever other variables are stored. But, they are "hidden". What does that mean? For example, they will not show up using `ls()` **unless** the `all.names` argument is `TRUE`. For example, consider `.a = 1; ls(); ls(all.names = TRUE); rm(.a); ls(all.names = TRUE)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declare variable with a dot at the begining in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553480/declare-variable-with-a-dot-at-the-begining-in-r)