# Conditional Join in Power Query/PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-manipulation, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a need to join two data sets based on a value in one data set being between values in another data set.

Data set 1 (foo):

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3 |
| b | 7 |
| c | 13 |

Data set 2 (bar):

| descr | beginval | endval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2 | 5 |
| y | 8 | 14 |
| z | 17 | 20 |

In SQL, I would write:

```sql
select bar.descr
, bar.beginval
, bar.endval
, foo.id
from bar
  left outer join foo on foo.val between bar.beginval and bar.endval
```

That would produce:

| descr | beginval | endval | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2 | 5 | a |
| y | 8 | 14 | c |
| z | 17 | 20 | (null) |

But since the data sets don't come from the same source, and the sources aren't necessarily SQL databases, I can't write SQL to do this in Power BI.

In Power BI, I'm seeing that I can join one column = one column.  I'm not seeing the ability to join to a range.  Is this possible with DAX or with some type of manipulation in Query Editor?

**Update**

In my specific case, data set 2 is a spreadsheet and data set 1 comes from a data mart.  If I join the data sets using M in Power Query Editor, as Davide Bacci recommends, it forces the result into Import mode.  Power BI became non-responsive and I ended up having to use Task Manager to kill Power BI when I noticed it was 20 million rows into a download that was likely to be several hundred million rows.

Is there a way to do this in DAX so I can leave the data mart part of this in Direct Query mode?  Or would that still result in a slow, resource-consuming join somewhere?  (Keep in mind that "slow" is relative and the main problem is the amount of computing resources required.  I'm currently doing this in IBM Cognos Analytics with the only problem being the report may take up to about 18 minutes to run.  But at least I'm not needing to upload a 400 GB dataset from my laptop to the report server.)

May I have asked a bit of an A-B question?  I'd be happy to learn there are other tools in the ecosystem that can help with this.  As long as it's not Power Automate.  That's forbidden here.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Not quite yet.  I may need to update my question.

Answer (score 2):

In Power Query:

A:

[image]

B:

[image]

Add a column and expand:

[image]

```
Table.SelectRows(B, (x)=> x[val] >= [beginval] and x[val] <= [endval])
```

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"descr", type text}, {"beginval", Int64.Type}, {"endval", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Table.SelectRows(B, (x)=> x[val] >= [beginval] and x[val] <= [endval])),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"id"}, {"id"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Comment: This is a really neat trick that technically does what I asked for -- but only if used for trivial data.  And Microsoft's documentation doesn't even approach this use case for `Table.SelectRows()`.  (Or maybe I need a fuller understanding of some core concepts in M.)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? This works on any kind of data and solves the problem with the  example data you provided. If you have some different problem, I suggest marking this as solved and asking a new question with the different data and output you have in mind.

Comment: Except that it makes Power BI Desktop unusable for hours while the data is downloading.  Then uploading all of that imported data to the Power BI service at 1/12th the download speed will never happen.  Besides, the online service implements a size restriction for Power BI (.pbix) files.  The problem here is a matter of scale.  The function and syntax you provided will work on a trivial data set, like combining two, small Excel files or a sample data set like AdventureWorks, but for data of non-trivial size, it causes more problems.

Comment: This is a different question to the one originally posed. My suggestion would be to start a new one with all the relevant information as this one is probably stale now.

Comment: Other than a statement clarifying that I'm using real data, not the 6 rows from my sample, the question has not changed.  I'll remove the part about the A-B question of that makes you feel better.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in Power BI, rather than Excel, you might leverage the [integration with R](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-r-in-query-editor) or Python.

## Approach

### Setup

Per the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-r-in-query-editor#use-an-r-script-in-power-query-editor), you can use R in a PQ step, like so:

> 6. From the **Transform** tab, select **Run R script**. The **Run R script** editor appears...
>    [image: 2]
> 7. ...enter the...script code in the **Script** box of the **Run R script** window.

You may enter an R script here, where your latest PQ data (`#"Changed Type"`) is *already* available, under the name `dataset`.

[image: 3]

This generates a step called `#"Run R script"` in PQ:

[image: 4]

### ⚠️ Note ⚠️

You may obviously edit this step, which is a call to `R.Execute()`.  Specifically, you may take an arbitrary set (`record`) of variables from your PQ environment, and pass them to the R environment.

**In place of the lone `dataset`, you should supply both `foo` and `bar` *simultaneously*:**

```m
= R.Execute("...", [foo = foo, bar = bar])
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

### Script

See the **R Solutions** section for some helpful scripts.  The big takeaway is that any result *must* be saved to the R environment

1. as a [`data.frame`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/data.frame.html) or subclass thereof; **and**
2. in a variable not [prefixed by `.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41554044).

You may use [`is.data.frame()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/as.data.frame.html) to check **(1)**, and [`as.data.frame()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/as.data.frame.html) to enforce it.  Subclasses of `data.frame` include [`tibble`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl_df-class.html)s and [`data.table`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/data.table.html)s.

```r
###############
## Preserved ##
###############

# A basic 'data.frame'
result_1 <- data.frame()

# The 'tibble' subclass of 'data.frame'
result_2 <- tibble::tibble()



##########
## Lost ##
##########

# Prefixed by '.'
.hidden_1 <- data.frame()

# Not a 'data.frame'
hidden_2 <- 42
```

### Results

All such `data.frame`s from your R environment are now available as `table`s in PQ, within the lookup `table` returned by `R.Execute()`:

[image: 8]

## R Solutions

These R scripts below will all yield a `result` with your desired `table` in PQ:

[image: 18]

[image: 19]

If your dataset is truly gargantuan...

> ...20 million rows into a download that was likely to be several hundred million rows.

...then the script with [**`data.table`**](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table) is your best bet: this package [features](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table#features)

> ...fast and scalable aggregations; e.g. 100GB in RAM (see [benchmarks](https://duckdblabs.github.io/db-benchmark) on up to **two billion rows**)

### With **`dplyr`**

The [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) package is ergonomic and pretty fast.  Here its [`join_by()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html) and [`between()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html) features facilitate your join:

```r
library(dplyr)

result <- bar %>%
  left_join(foo, join_by(between(y$val, x$beginval, x$endval))) %>%
  select(descr, beginval, endval, id)
```

### With **`sqldf`**

The [**`sqldf`**](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#readme) package emulates SQL in an R environment.  A bit Inception-y for my taste, but your own SQL translates verbatim:

```r
library(sqldf)

result <- sqldf('
  select bar.descr
  , bar.beginval
  , bar.endval
  , foo.id
  from bar
    left outer join foo on foo.val between bar.beginval and bar.endval
')
```

### With **`data.table`**

The [**`data.table`**](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table) package sacrifices ergonomics for [blazing performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718317).  Observe how `bar LEFT JOIN foo` is flipped in translation to `foo`[`[`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/data.table.html#ref-usage)`bar`[`, ...]`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/data.table.html#ref-usage).

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(foo)
setDT(bar)

result <- foo[bar,
  # Selection.
  .(descr = i.descr, beginval = i.beginval, endval = i.endval, id = x.id),
  
  # Join.
  on = .(val >= beginval, val <= endval)
]
```

---

## Further Reading

- [*"The unequalled joy of non-equi joins"*](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/the-unequalled-joy-of-non-equi-joins)
- [*"Overlap joins"*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html#overlap-joins) with **`dplyr`**
- [*"R data.table Joins"*](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/r-data-table-joins-48f00b46ce29)
- [*"Database-like ops benchmark"*](https://duckdblabs.github.io/db-benchmark)